# restore windows permission from linux

Tags: linux, windows, partitioning, permissions

i'm using linux, but my windows partition is not detected,
i'm trying to setting in my fstab, and its work.
when i access windows file its must be have root accees, and my mistake is give all files on my windows partition with chmod 777, i'm forget to give a permission when make a folder for first time. its be my windows file not be access from windows os, and must be access on linux.
anyone can help me?

Comment: You can't chmod a NTFS partition to 777 that doesn't make sense

Comment: @Ramhound its make sense, my file in windows can't be execute with windows, but in my linux its work.